# Javascript Replace all but what is inside of title=""

Tags: javascript

I have this text

```
var test = "<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="2Test">1TEST</span>";
```

I don't rely not sure what I am doing and could need some help. This is what I tried:

```
test = test.replace(/<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="|">[^>]*>/gi, "");
```

The test variable should only return the value inside of "title".

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: Why do you want to parse instead of simply accessing the DOM and reading the value you need?

Comment: *"I have this text"* – not really, that's a syntax error…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Biffen you shouldn't really parse HTML with regex! But if you must do it, try this...

```
var test = "<span data-toggle='tooltip' title='2Test'>1TEST</span>";
var result = test.match(/title='([^']+)'/)[1];

console.log(result); //2Test
```

Comment: This works fine but only if the variable 'test' contains "title" if "title" isn't there it trows an error. Like `var test = "normal text"`. But I will find a solution for that myself thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse HTML to get the title attribute, instead you can access title attribute from HTML DOM.

Create a temporary container with `createElement`, then set inner html with your html string, lastly traverse to first child which is the `span` and get the `title` attribute that you want.

Example:

```js
var test = "<span data-toggle='tooltip' title='2Test'>1TEST</span>";

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = test;
var title = el.firstChild.getAttribute('title')
console.log(title) //2Test
```